# Multiple Async call resolutions using Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

In Node.js, I have a Promise.all(array) resolution with a resulting value that I need to combine with the results of another asynchronous function call. I am having problems getting the results of this second function, since it resolves later than the promise.all. I could add it to the Promise.all, but it would ruin my algorithm. Is there a way to get these values outside of their resolutions so I can modify them statically? Can I create a container that waits for their results?

To be more specific, I am reading from a Firebase realtime database that has been polling API data. I need to run an algorithm on this data and store it in a MongoDB archive. But the archive opens aynchronously and I can't get it to open before my results resolve (which need to be written).

Example:

```
module.exports = {
news: async function getNews() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://cryptopanic.com/api/posts/?auth_token=518dacbc2f54788fcbd9e182521851725a09b4fa&public=true');
        //console.log(response.data.results);
        var news = [];
        response.data.results.forEach((results) => {
            news.push(results.title);
            news.push(results.published_at);
            news.push(results.url);
        });
        console.log(news);
        return news;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
},
coins: async function resolution() {
    await Promise.all(firebasePromise).then((values) => {
       //code
       return value
 }
}
```

I have tried the first solution, and it works for the first entry, but I may be writing my async function wrong on my second export, because it returns undefined.

Comment: `async` and `await` model would be a better choice.

Comment: Would help if you provide more context (code). You could wrap the first `Promise.all` and the second funtion in another `Promise.all`

Comment: I would like to export them separately and recombine them. Elsewhere. I am looking at EMCA6 exports as they are async, but I do not have much experience with them. This is the backend of a React app.

Comment: You have to wait for your archive to open and then call `getNews()`. The same can be achieved by wrapping the open archive logic in `promise` or `async` function call.

Comment: Thank you I have been working on this line of thought.

Comment: The solution below works for the first part, but I have added the second part, which is still returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a Promise from `getNews`

```
   module.exports = {
     news: function getNews() {
         return axios.get('https://cryptopanic.com/api/posts/?auth_token=518dacbc2f54788fcbd9e182521851725a09b4fa&public=true')
         .then(res => {
         // Do your stuff
         return res;
       })
     }
   }
```

and then

```
 let promiseSlowest = news();

 let promiseOther1 = willResolveSoon1();
 let promiseOther2 = willResolveSoon2();
 let promiseOther3 = willResolveSoon3();

 Promise.all([ promiseOther1, promiseOther2, promiseOther3 ]).then([data1, 
 data2, data3] => {
    promiseSlowest.then(lastData => {
       // data1, data2, data3, lastData all will be defined here
    })
 })
```

The benefit here is all promises will start and run concurrently so your total waiting time will be equal to the time taken by the `promiseSlowest`.

Check the link for more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Examples

Comment: I tried this result. It worked for the first part, but my promise.all resolution returns undefined. I may be writing the async/await wrong.

Comment: @EzraCook if you can share the code by using https://jsfiddle.net or something then it will be easier for me to know how you want it.

Comment: @EzraCook never ever put your secret keys inside your code especially in public repos , you did in https://github.com/m0bi/bitcoin/blob/5108b161eb854fedf08ca71872bd5e436b546ef9/logic.js#L32 use environment variables instead.

Comment: I have fixed the error. The problem was my const values = async promise.all(array); works while  async promise.all(array).then((values)=>{}); does not.

Comment: You mean `const values = await Promise.all(array)` ?

Comment: Yes I agree with you on my typo and also on .env protection. The only keys in my repo are public keys which are accessible via websites API or dev sections (except for a bot in my comments which I need to remove, thanks).